# How to extract all fields from JSON schema?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame but all of my columns are “inside” one columns how can I extract that other columns from that one column? `Spark.parallelize(table)` is returns:

> “Typeerror: cannot pickle ‘_thread.Rlock’ object

Below is the schema:

```
root
|-- table: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- school: date (nullable = true)
|    |-- studentid: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- class: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
```

```py
schema1 = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("school", DateType(), True),
    StructField("StudentID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("class", StringType(), True),
    StructField("grade", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("age", StringType(), True),
])
```

```py
table = df.select(from_json(col("body").cast("string"), schema1).alias("table"))
table.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract all the struct fields into columns using something like this:

```
df = df.select('table.*')
```